# About reviewing questions

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Now that I have more than 1K rep, I get  the `reviewing` feature which I hate, I'm not into moderation. I hate being a judge. So far I skipped all reviews but today I saw two reviews that I want to ask  you about

The first is this

[image]

Basically the editor just indented the question, would you accept such edit? Or is it point farming? How would this edit help make the question better? What rules do you follow when doing the reviewing?

The other question was edited by a spamer who removed the whole question and inserted some stupid text, what to do about it? I marked it as a spam but should I take further action to ban him from the entire SE network or something?

**EDIT**

I started a feature request on Meta.SO: [Add captcha to anonymous edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223900/add-captcha-to-anonymous-edits), please support this feature by voting it up if you agree.

Comment: About the last paragraph: I have observed this kind of spam attack at least ten times the last couple of weeks. Is this a new phenomenon, or has it always been like this?

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen I don't know, we should ask someone

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen, the spam attacks have just cropped up, at least as far as I am aware.

Comment: @EdDean how come anonymous users edit questions? someone just tried  to edit the question `is chess a game of luck...`  it seems that he didn't even sign up, no account, anonymous user

Comment: I'm not sure why it was decided to allow suggested edits from anonymous users (as opposed to only from registered lower-rep users), but it does seem to be by design. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147293/why-am-i-getting-many-suggested-edits-by-anonymous-users

Comment: @EdDean please read my edit

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen please read my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the edit isn't actually the indent, it's the [addition of an appropriate tag](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/1412/revisions). This is valid and helpful. However, if it *was* simply that indent, I would reject it, since that's really a matter of style, and there's no call to impose your style on other users.

I always accept even small edits that are correctly done. While I suppose it's possible to be motivated by the rep alone to make tiny changes, it's not really easy to tell unless there is a flood of trivial edits from a user. Per se, I would rather accept a mini improvement than reject it in the name of foiling greed that might not exist.

If I see a ton of micro edits from a particular user, I would likely reject the lot. But I haven't seen this much, and not at all on this site.

As far as the spam edit goes, you should reject the edit as spam, but an anonymous user can't be banned.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "too minor" reason is more for the benefit of the trilogy sites. On a smaller exchange like ours, the volume of suggested edits is significantly lower, and therefore doesn't eat up massive amounts of reviewer time. Thus, it's not a bad thing to be inclusive with edits that are genuine improvements. (That may change as the site grows, of course.)